# OSError while importing manually uploaded pytorch from Glue

Tags: pytorch, aws-glue

I'm about to produce datasets to train an AI model from raw data in RDS, using Glue. By some policies of the company(maybe internet block), The magic `%additional_python_modules` doesn't work. So I uploaded the zipped module to S3, and used `%extra_py_files s3://<bucket>/<prefix>/torch_linux.zip` to import the module, but got the error message below:

`OSError: /tmp/torch_linux.zip/torch/lib/libtorch_global_deps.so: cannot open shared object file: Not a directory`

I used WSL to download the module with `pip3 install torch --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu`, so libtorch_global_deps.so file is present in /lib, and I presume the problem is not associated with cuda availability. I checked that the module is imported without any problem in my computer, and the computer and Glue both run on x86-64 architecture as well.

I tried  `os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] += ':/tmp/torch_linux.zip/torch/'`, but it didn't work. It actually didn't seem to have the package file in its directory anyway; I ran `!ls -la` in Glue interactive session(Jupyter notebook) and couldn't find any file related to the module.

This is my first question in S/O, so please feel free for correcting any mistakes, suggestions for readability, or requiring information for the problem, etc.

Comment: Hi, it wasn't a problem of additional_python_modules at the first place. The DB manager accidently blocked access from Glue, which led to connection timeout. And it somehow resulted in module error, without any clue about DB on my screen. I wonder if I could have figured this out with CloudWatch permission.